# Java - Calculating hour difference - specific scenario

Tags: java, time

I just want to calculate time difference in minutes, hopefully there is already a class which does it correctly.
So the values which I get from the website are only Hours and Minutes (for instance: event **starts** at: **20:30** and **ends** at **03:30**).

When I use 'Duration.between' I get incorrect values - it is happening when the first value is greater than  second or second is past midnight. 
I think I would be able to do this with 'ifs' and 'elses' but I am sure that there is already a class or a method which would solve the issue in more elegant way, but I can't find it. 
Here is my code: it works only when the second value is greater than first:

```
        LocalTime eventStarts = LocalTime.now();
        LocalTime eventEnds = LocalTime.now();
        eventStarts = eventStarts.withHour(22).withMinute(00);
        eventEnds = eventEnds.withHour(03).withMinute(00);

        Duration durationBetweenEvents =  Duration.between(eventStarts, eventEnds);


        System.out.println(durationBetweenEvents.toMinutes());
```

in this case i get '-1140'

Comment: `eventEnds = eventEnds.withHour(03).withMinute(00)` is setting the ending time to a time in the same day, which is the same day you set `eventStarts` to, but an earlier time. So your ending time is intentionally earlier than your starting time.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following to your code.

```
if (durationBetweenEvents.isNegative()) {
    durationBetweenEvents = durationBetweenEvents.plusDays(1);
}
```

You have to be a little careful with daylight savings.  Your calculation can be an hour out, if daylight savings time starts or ends between the events.  But without knowing date or timezone information, there's no way to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

## Need dates & time zone

`LocalTime` has no notion of dates or days. So it is limited to a single generic 24-hour day. Going from an evening time to a morning time is viewed as going backwards in time, not wrapping around to another day as no days exist.

To know the duration of an actual event you need dates and time zone.

Getting the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

Once you have dates, apply a `ZoneId` to get `ZonedDateTime` objects. From there you can get a `Duration` that takes into account anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 );

ZonedDateTime zdtStart = 
    ZonedDateTime.of( today , LocalTime.parse( "20:30" ) , z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = 
    ZonedDateTime.of( tomorrow , LocalTime.parse( "03:30" ) , z ) ;

Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtStop ) ;

long totalMinutes = d.toMinutes() ;
```

> zdtStart.toString(): 2017-04-13T20:30-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> zdtStop.toString(): 2017-04-14T03:30-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> d.toString(): PT7H
>
> totalMinutes: 420

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/S3KHLD).

Comment: OP writes "... the values which I get from the website are only Hours and Minutes ..." so this isn't going to cut it.